# Interact with pdf files in web browser - visualise pdf and highlight words / phrases

Tags: pdf, web-browser, pdf-viewer

Is there software, ideally open source that will allow me to visualise a pdf in a web browser and interact with the text?

I want to be able to have a list of words and highlight them in the browser.

The icing on the cake would be if I could also save the 'marked up' pdf.

I wish to have full control over the code and be able to modify or enhance it to suit my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Mozilla's open source library [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). This is what powers Firefox's built-in PDF viewer.

Live demos are available [here](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/), with [more examples in the Github repository](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vender that distributes the LEADTOOLS SDK.***

If you want to consider a commercial product, you could look at the LEADTOOLS Document Viewer for web.

It can load and save different types of documents and can add mark-up to the files and then save them into a separate XML file or on the original document as an overlay.

The Document Viewer has text search functionality that allows you to search through a document for specific text, which can be used alongside the mark-up functionality. This
will allow you to highlight specific portions of text within your document. There’s an online demo where you can see all the features here:
https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/index.html

Here is a screenshot of the mark-up:
[image: screenshot of demo]

Here is the documentation for the Document Viewer, Annotations, find, and hilite functions, respectively:

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/javascript/to/using-the-leadtools-document-viewer.html

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/doxui/documentviewerannotations.html

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/javascript/doxui/documentviewertext-find.html

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/ac/annhiliteobject.html

Comment: Do you have any pricing information?

Comment: All I could find was 'Special volume pricing is available'.

Comment: You can check the pricing tab on this link: https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document-imaging-suite

Also you can reach out to sales@leadtools.com for more specific pricing for your needs

Comment: **OUCH** 5k for 1 license!!